# Как я могу запустить проект Django c чужого репозитория github на своем пк?

Tags: python, django

Есть проект [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://github.com/and-nothing-else/marketplace)

Хочу запустить его на своей машине локально.
Какие действия мне надо сделать что бы он заработал.

Comment: Об этом должен рассказывать разработчик проекта, а не мы

Comment: `git clone`, `requirements`, `runserver` не работает?

Comment: нет, уже два дня мучаюсь